# Maven Dependencies not in WEB-INF/lib directory after Deployment Assembly set

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I've seen this question on stack overflow and the answer was to set the deployment assembly.  I did that and I still am not getting my maven dependencies in my WEB-INF/lib directory.

[image]

[image]

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers kepler and open JDK 8.  With the mavin plug in.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really follow the [default folder layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) based on the given pictures it does not look like. BTW: If you haven't change many things in Eclipse you are using Maven 3 and not Maven 2(tagged with Maven 2).

Comment: @khmarbaise It should be a Elipse dynamic web project.  If it is not then I can tell you I've tried it on multiple dynamic web projects.  I'm not sure if that follows the default folder layout but I will try that.  The plug in is m2e.  I'm not sure how to determine if it's maven 2.  Do you know how to find that out?

Comment: If this an up-to-date Eclipse it's defintively not Maven 2. It's maven 3.X

Comment: I'm not going to make this the answer but I did find out my tomcat configuration was wrong.  I completely reinstalled eclipse and reinstalled tomcat and I was getting working webpages without any jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: I'm seeing the same (or similar) symptoms.  I've set up the Maven Dependencies -> /WEB-INF/lib mapping in Deployment Assembly, and I'm getting one of the dependencies copied (spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar) but nothing else.  Getting seriously frustrated by this.